# Create sub site using workflow in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sub-site

I have one project list in site collection and want to create a subsite when a new item is inserted in Project list. Is it possible using workflow?

Note: I am using Office365 account.

If this is not possible then please suggest me another way to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action to create a new site isn't included in the actions available by default in SharePoint (Designer) workflows.
It's possible to develop a custom workflow action to add this capability to the workflows in your site collection.

Technically this can be achieved by creating a sandbox solution which contains the custom action for SharePoint Designer, and activate this custom solution in your site collection

Comment: Hi massimo Prota, Thanx for the answer but I am using Online Office 365 Account so can't create Sandbox solution.

Comment: Dear Ashok, what you assert isn't true.
Sandbox solutions are still supported in SharePoint Online (365). Sandbox solutions containing code are deprecated, but still a possibility.

Comment: This answer is false. With the REST API and an App step you can create new subsites with workflow. https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8661/create-site-from-template-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow

Comment: my first answer is false? Well I'd say it is partially: indeed there's no specific OOB action to create sub-sites directly, but can be achieved by using another activity adapted for this purpose. I don't see I state anywhere that is the *only* way of achieving that

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2013 Workflows was introduced a new action named `Call HTTP Web Service`. Using the specified action you could consume SharePoint REST API, in particular `/_api/web/webinfos/add` endpoint to create web site from a workflow.

Please follow [Consuming the SharePoint 2013 REST Service from SharePoint Designer](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/08/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-service-from-sharepoint-designer/) post that describes how to configure `Call HTTP Web Service` in order to create web site.

> In order to perform Create/Update/Delete operations using  Call HTTP
>   Web Service action, App permissions for workflow have to be
>   configured.  Please follow the steps in article [Create a workflow
>   with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint 2013 Workflow
>   platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to configure App permissions for workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to suggested approach with calling web service, but it is quite complex to implement.

There is a workflow action called [Create Site](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/Actions/Administration.html#create-site) in [Workflow Action Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/). 
It allows creating SharePoint sites cross-site from a template.

It is paid third party solution with many other workflow actions. I'm a part of the development team.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above to create a site, but it didn't create the site nor errored.  Here are the logs of the dictionaries I wrote out.  Please advise.

> 2/13/2019 1:36 AM Comment  No presence informationHoward Bash   Url:
>   https://somesite.sharepoint.com/sites/OfficeDevelopment/DataKloudDev/_api/web/webinfos
>       2/13/2019 1:36 AM Comment  No presence informationHoward Bash   Metadata: {"type":"SP.WebInfoCreationInformation"}
>       2/13/2019 1:36 AM Comment  No presence informationHoward Bash   WebParameters:
>   {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.WebInfoCreationInformation"},"Url":"MadeInCode","Description":"MadeInCode","Language":2,"WebTemplate":"sts","UseIniquePermissions":false}
>       2/13/2019 1:36 AM Comment  No presence informationHoward Bash   RequestHeaders:
>   {"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type":"application/json;odata=verbose"}
>       2/13/2019 1:36 AM Comment  No presence informationHoward Bash   RequestContent
>   {"parameters":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.WebInfoCreationInformation"},"Url":"MadeInCode","Description":"MadeInCode","Language":2,"WebTemplate":"sts","UseIniquePermissions":false}}

Comment: Your WebTemplate and UseUniquePermissions parameters don't look right. UseUniquePermissions should be spelt as I have, replace the capital I with a U. The WebTemplate should read sts#0 (assuming you are trying to create a team site).